# Server Deployment on NGINX of Nuxt project not showing homepage

Tags: nginx, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have created a new Nuxt project based on a base client project to make a headless web app. I am hosting the project on a NGINX server. I am using Pm2 to keep the app alive and this is running on port 3000. I have setup a proxy pass in Plesk in order to get the app running. The good news is: sub urls are all working, so if I go to /news or /blog etc it works properly. If I go from /news back to home I also get the homepage.

But if I go the home url (/) I get a 403 error. I have tried everything, like setting permissions of the root folder or further editing the config file. All to no avail.

When I test my app locally I have no such problem whatsoever. If I add an index.html file in the root folder, I get a 404 error instead of a 403.

These are my Additional nginx directives in Plesk:

```
location ~ / {
proxypass http://127.0.0.1:3000; proxyhttpversion 1.1; proxysetheader Upgrade 
$httpupgrade;
proxysetheader Connection 'upgrade';
proxysetheader Host $host;
proxycachebypass $httpupgrade; proxysetheader X-Real-IP $remoteaddr;
proxysetheader X-Forwarded-For $proxyaddxforwardedfor;
}
```

Anybody knows what this could be? The oddest thing to me is that this only happens on the homepage. I have a test url over here:
http://silo-2018.silotest.nl...

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? having a similar issue